# How to modify reference value (driven and driving mode) for the constant dimension in sketch by catia VBA

Tags: vba, reference, catia

I would like to change reference value (driven or driving mode) for constraint dimension in sketch by vba catia.

Usually, we want to change reference value two method without automatic:

1. Double click constrains dimension.
2. Click right mouse and choose definition
   And then the Constraint definition Box appears and select "Reference".

Now, I want to write Macro when i select the constraint dimension and run macro, it will be change the reference value.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you run into troubles?